# JavaScript bulleted list generation

Tags: javascript

I'm using Rails 2.2, and as well as standard JavaScript libraries, we jQuery also.

Given that, can anyone advise me of a starting point in creating a UI component which would allow users to create a bulleted list, adding bullets/deleting bullets/indenting sub-bullets etc? I'm not bound to using the libraries we already have, but consider it preferable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like TinyMCE? You can customize it to have whatever controls you want.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Answer (score 0):

Will the [treeview plug-in](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/) do for you? It is not a bulleted list, but it is an off-the-shelf component that will allow you to create an ordered set of elements.